# Retrofit Custom Callback Generic Type

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm extending the default Retrofit 2 Callback:

```
abstract class APICallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Cast response.body() to my POJO class, results in null
            MyClass myClass = (MyClass) response.body();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        // TODO ...
    }
}
```

How can I downcast the generic type of the Response to my own class?
Should this process be automatic? I'm using GsonConverter for the client.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to Modify AdapterFactory and then register retrofit

```
public class APICallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {

@Nullable
@Override
public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    final Type responseType = ((ParameterizedType) returnType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return new CallAdapter<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Type responseType() {
            return responseType;
        }

        @Override
        public Object adapt(Call<Object> call) {
            return new APICallAdapter<>(call);
        }
    };
}
```

and

```
 private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(APIService.baseUrl)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(new APICallAdapterFactory())
        .build();
```

Comment: Add summary of that link here and demonstrate with some sample code.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it :) @Satendra

Comment: Although this is old, you recently posted one (now deleted) NAA with a link to that blog. According to your profile, that is your blog. So as a friendly reminder, remember that you need to add disclosure whenever you link to your own blog. Also, excessive self-promotion also puts your posts at risk of being flagged as spam. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

**Replace T with MyClass**

```
class APICallback implements Callback<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyClass> call, Response<MyClass> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Cast response.body() to my POJO class, results in null
             MyClass myClass = response.body();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyClass> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that, I'm overriding a generic type.

Comment: remove abstract & "!"(response.isSuccessful()), use above  updated code working fine

Comment: please check the answer which I provide below

Answer (score 0):

You can process by this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass myClass = gson.fromJson(response.body(), MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Should this not be automatic via the GsonConverter I've added to the Retrofit setup?

Comment: No. you have to add this in gradle dependecy and you should write JsonElement instead of your class in Response<MyClass> response